# Can I install from a Windows 10 ISO or USB stick and still get the free upgrade?

Tags: windows-10, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade my Win7 system to Windows 10 (because I am, apparently, masochistic). It's not working, locking up at about 30 to 35%, requiring me to reset, which then backs out the upgrade.

The whole process takes about three to four hours. A large part of this is having to download 3.5GB of upgrade every time, because Microsoft's tool doesn't cache the install files.

The tool has an option to create a bootable USB stick, which I can use to do an install. This should be way faster.

However, Microsoft seem really firm that if I want to get my free upgrade, I need to pick to 'Upgrade this PC' option from the upgrade tool. This seems peculiar. Can anyone confirm (i.e. who *actually knows* from first hand knowledge) whether upgrading from a USB stick actually works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do the upgrade through the ISO.

> Please be aware that you cannot use the free upgrade offer to perform a clean install on first attempt. You must first upgrade from the qualifying version of Windows 7 or Windows 8/8.1 (whether you do it through **Windows Update** *or* **using the .ISO file**).

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-upgrade-from-previous-versions-of-windows/31722b30-1da9-42bb-b331-0edc4649bf43

Comment: Thanks very much. That needs to be way, *way* clearer...

Comment: Yeah, I don't particularly like how Microsoft handled the launch of Windows 10. I may eventually upgrade in the distant future, but not now...